Playwright unable to Fetch JSON Data in Offline HTML File using Javascript
I'm trying to render an HTML form using data from a JSON file with JavaScript, so that i can save a populated form as a pdf. When I open the index.html file directly from the filesystem (using the file:// protocol), It's unable to fetch the JSON data required to populate the form. The Javascript has also not run.
I have a Playwright script that navigates to the local HTML file and attempts to render it.
with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    page = browser.new_page()
    current_directory = os.getcwd()
    index_html_path = os.path.join(current_directory, 'temp', 'index.html')
    index_html_url = f'file://{index_html_path}'
    page.goto(index_html_url)
    page.pdf(path='formoffline.pdf')
    print('Saved formoffline.pdf')
    browser.close()

I expected the JSON data to be loaded and processed without issues. Instead, the output is just the plain HTML without any of the Javascript or JSON loaded. This issue occurs when I use Playwright to open the HTML file. When I run a server using liveserver or node, it is properly working in the same directory. I'm not sure what is causing this issue or how to resolve it.
I want to avoid running a server for this, that will work and i have a solution with it, but I want to reduce the overhead as much as possible.
Minimal reproducible example:
gen.py
import os
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

def generate_pdf():
    with sync_playwright() as p:
        browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=True)
        page = browser.new_page()
        current_directory = os.getcwd()
        index_html_path = os.path.join(current_directory, 'index.html')
        index_html_url = f'file://{index_html_path}'
        page.goto(index_html_url)
        page.pdf(path='output.pdf')
        browser.close()

generate_pdf()

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Minimal Reproducible Example</title>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>

script.js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const contentDiv = document.getElementById("content");

    fetch("data.json")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            const message = data.message;
            contentDiv.innerHTML = `<p>${message}</p>`;
        })
        .catch(error => console.error("Error loading JSON:", error));
});

data.json
{
    "message": "This is dynamic content loaded from a JSON file."
}


As you discovered, you'll need to run a web server to host the site and serve those static assets. Or inline them into the .html file. Or set them dynamically onto the page with evaluate (depending on your actual use case). Can you provide a bit more context (desired result) and a [mcve] with index.html and the assets? If you have the live server version working, then you're good to go, and the problem is solved, right?

Yes, a server will work, but i want to avoid using it to reduce the overhead. I already havea. solution that works with a server using python http.server and socketserver, but i'm trying to achieve the result with lowest overhead possible.

@ggorlen I have added the minimal reproducible example.

Thanks, looks good. Well, serving the files is sort of the only option short of changing the index.html. Please describe your use case: can you change the index.html, and what sort of server are you running this on in production (if applicable)?

I added an answer--if it doesn't work for you, then please provide a less contrived example (you may have simplified too much).

The main options are to run a server (in production, this should be no problem, right?), inject the data into the HTML with string manipulation and use set_content, or use evaluate to inject the data into the content once it's rendered.
Since you're already aware of the first option, and option 2 requires some modifications to the HTML and/or potential hackiness (consider using a templating engine like Jinja2 to handle the string injection), here's the last option applied to your example:
import os
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright # 1.43.0


def generate_pdf():
    with sync_playwright() as p:
        browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=True)
        page = browser.new_page()

        with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "index.html")) as f:
            page.set_content(f.read())

        with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "data.json")) as f:
            js = f"e => e.innerHTML = `<p>{f.read()}</p>`"
            page.locator("#content").evaluate(js)

        page.pdf(path="output.pdf")
        browser.close()


generate_pdf()

If you're happy with this, remove the fetch from your HTML code to avoid an unnecessary in-browser error and simplify your code. You're now "fetching" the data with Playwright from the file system on behalf of the website.
With that in mind, you could also intercept the request with Playwright and mock the response JSON, but this seems a bit overengineered for such a simple scenario. For that matter, you could even mock fetch to return the JSON directly.
